# Create instance specification code in Rhapsody

Tags: rhapsody, sysml

I am working on a Rhapsody SysML project for work and we need to be able to model different  configurations of our system. To give a concrete example, if our system is a vehicle, we want to be able to simulate that vehicle with different configurations of engines, wheels, etc.

This is my first time using SysML but in the book *A Practical Guide to SysML* it discusses, in chapter 7, the concept of Instance Specifications. These sound like exactly what we need, and Rhapsody appears to have support for them. So we created an Instance Specification in Rhapsody, giving it specific values for the engine and wheels. But once we create the instance specification we cannot find any way to actually create an instance from that specification. We noticed that Rhapsody doesn't even generate any code for the instance specification.

So my questions are the following, can Instance Specifications be used to create different configurations of a system and if so how? If not, what is the best method for modeling different configurations of a system?

Thanks for any help you can provide.